# How to refrence a model from a dll file in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dll, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to MVC and DLL and Stackoverflow so please be patient with me and ask if anything in this question doesn't make sense.

I have an MVC5 project in which I have been asked to use a DLL file already made to do some basic CRUD functions using models from within the DLL file, however I do not know how to reference a DLL file or how to then extract the model details from it. Have I misunderstood what has been asked of me or is this something which can be done?

Comment: just add a reference to the dll  to your web project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For adding a reference to a dll in the project:**

1- In Solution Explorer, select your Web project.

2- Right-click the name of your Web project in Solution Explorer and then select Add Reference. The Add Reference dialog box is displayed.

3- Select the Browse tab.

4- Browse to the folder that contains the dll you want to reference, select the dll, and then click OK.

To use the dll:

let us say that you want to use the dll inside the Home controller:

```
namespace YourProject.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        #region Actions
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            try
            {
              NameofYourdll.ClassName tVar = new NameofYourdll.ClassName();
             tVar.Create();
                return View();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               throw;
            }
        }
        #endregion
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no special requirement to do this.
Simply add a reference to this dll in your project and reference the model using its fully qualified name or just its name (if you've added a using statement for its namespace).

If you add your dll `MyExternal.dll` to your project and it contains a model `MyExternal.MyModel` you can simply reference the model anywhere in your code.

Comment: I thought it might be this simple, thank you! @scartag